# ksoap2 - how to define additional charactistics of a property

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

If I have to supply below xml:

```
           <Text>
             <TypeCode>SU99</TypeCode>
             <ContentText>This is a test incident.</ContentText>
           </Text>
```

I would write my code something like this:

```
           SoapObject Text = new SoapObject ("", "Text");
           Text.addProperty("TypeCode", "SU99");
           Text.addProperty("ContentText", txtDet.getText().toString());
```

But how about below xml? ContentText has additional property called languageCode. How do I define that? Any suggestion please?

```
           <Text>
              <TypeCode>SU99</TypeCode>
             <ContentText languageCode="EN">This is a test incident.</ContentText>
           </Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve it using below code:

```
                        SoapObject Text = new SoapObject ("", "Text");
                        Text.addProperty("TypeCode", "SU99");
                        SoapPrimitive ContentText = new SoapPrimitive("", "ContentText", txtDet.getText().toString());
                        ContentText.addAttribute("languageCode","EN");
                        Text.addProperty("ContentText", ContentText);
```